# Scraping multiple pages in one Beautiful Soup script -- getting same result

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to loop through a script that parses tables with Beautiful Soup in Python 2.7.

The first table parse works and produces the expected results.  The second loop produces exactly the same results as the first loop.
Additional details:

- If I manually use the url that the second loop used to parse, I get
  the intended page that I want to scrape.  There is a little delay in refresh.
- I use this on other websites and the loop works as intended.

Here is the script:

```
    import urllib2
    import csv
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup # latest version bs4

    week = raw_input("Which week?")
    week = str(week)
    data = []
    first = "http://fantasy.nfl.com/research/projections#researchProjections=researchProjections%2C%2Fresearch%2Fprojections%253Foffset%253D"
    middle = "%2526position%253DO%2526sort%253DprojectedPts%2526statCategory%253DprojectedStats%2526statSeason%253D2015%2526statType%253DweekProjectedStats%2526statWeek%253D"
    last = "%2Creplace"
    page_num = 1
    for page_num in range(1,3):
        page_mult = (page_num-1) * 25 +1
        next = str(page_mult)
        url = first + next + middle + week + last
    print url #I added this in order to check my output
    html = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html,"lxml")
    table = soup.find('table', attrs={'class':'tableType-player hasGroups'})
    table_body = table.find('tbody')

    rows = table_body.find_all('tr')
    for row in rows:
        cols = row.find_all('td')
        cols = [ele.text.strip() for ele in cols]
        data.append([ele for ele in cols if ele]) # Get rid of empty values
    b = open('NFLtable.csv', 'w')
    a = csv.writer(b)
    a.writerows(data)
    b.close()
    page_num =page_num+1
    print data
```

Comment: I'm not sure to understand, you want to scrape two pages but are only getting one with your script?

Comment: Kind of.  I'm scraping the first page fine.  When it is in the second iteration of the loop, it creates the second url correctly, but returns the results from the first page again.  So, if there are 25 records per page, I'm getting 50 records in my CSV, but the first 25 are identical to the last 25.  If I iterate this beyond the second loop, I get the first 25 records again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the actual page they are using AJAX to request additional results, with a JSON response with some HTML as one of the values.

I modified your code a bit, give it a try:

```
import urllib2
import urllib
import csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup  # latest version bs4
import json

week = raw_input("Which week?")
week = str(week)
data = []
url_format = "http://fantasy.nfl.com/research/projections?offset={offset}&position=O&sort=projectedPts&statCategory=projectedStats&statSeason=2015&statType=weekProjectedStats&statWeek={week}"

for page_num in range(1, 3):
    page_mult = (page_num - 1) * 25 + 1
    next = str(page_mult)
    url = url_format.format(week=week, offset=page_mult)
    print url  # I added this in order to check my output

    request = urllib2.Request(url, headers={'Ajax-Request': 'researchProjections'})
    raw_json = urllib2.urlopen(request).read()
    parsed_json = json.loads(raw_json)
    html = parsed_json['content']

    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
    table = soup.find('table', attrs={'class': 'tableType-player hasGroups'})
    table_body = table.find('tbody')

    rows = table_body.find_all('tr')
    for row in rows:
        cols = row.find_all('td')
        cols = [ele.text.strip() for ele in cols]
        data.append([ele for ele in cols if ele])  # Get rid of empty values

print data
```

I tested with week=4.

Comment: Thanks a ton for the help -- this worked.  I didn't know the difference from scraping and making a call to ensure I scraped the correct data.